# How to link a specific view to a custom form in Dynamics 365 CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365-sales

I am currently working on customizing an entity in Dynamics 365 CRM, and I have a requirement to associate a specific view with a custom form. Here's what I want to achieve:

When users select the "Contact - Visitor" view, I want them to be able to create new records using the custom form "Contact - Visitor Form." This form contains custom fields and a different layout compared to the default main form.

For all other views, including the default "Active Contacts" view, I want users to be able to create new records using the standard main form, which is the default form used throughout the system.

I have tried exploring the form settings and views customization options, but I haven't found a direct way to link a view to a specific form. By default, all views seem to use the main form for new record creation.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior in Dynamics 365 CRM? If so, what steps do I need to follow to associate a view with a custom form?

I would appreciate any guidance or insights from the community. Thank you!

Comment: first idea is to create a custom button inside the ribbon (called "new" and hiding the default one) to try to implement your logic (so check which view is currently opened) but right now I can't guarantee is doable

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Contact - Visitor" is a special type of contact and you want to capture different information for this contact as compared to others. if this is the case then ..
1- Create an Option Set **Contact Type** with values (Contact Person, Visitor)

2- Create special form for "Visitor"

3- Place "Contact Type" on both Forms (Main, Visitor)

4- For new records: When the user selects "Contact Type" then load a Form accordingly using javascript: [Switch Forms in Microsoft Dynamics CRM depending on Business Logic](https://crmminds.com/2022/10/16/dynamics-365-switch-forms-dynamically-by-using-javascript/)

5- For existing records: On Form load, write java-script which should load the Form based on Contact Type.